# Select something for a column whose value is stored in a temporary variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two input tables
input_table_1 looks like this:

```
prod_id store id    net_sales   gender  color
1   1   34  m   blue
2   1   43  f   green
3   2   12  f   green
4   3   22  f   blue
5   3   56  m   black
6   3   4   f   green
```

second table is look_up_table which has column names of table 1 and their values:

```
attribut  value_1
gender  m
gender  f
color   blue
color   green
color   black
.           .
.           .
.           .
```

I have created this code where i run nested loops and store values of attribute and value_1 in temp variables. now i want to select sum of net_sales from input_table_1 where column name is as stored in temp_atr_val and cell value is as temp_val. 
I am trying something like this but its not working for me and the temp_sales variable doesn't take any value. please help how i can use select statement to select sum of sales for particular value of attribute.

the code:

```
declare 
temp_atr_val varchar2(400);
temp_val varchar2 (400);
temp_name varchar2 (400);
temp_sum_percent decimal (10,3);
temp_variable number := 786;
column_count number ; 
val_count number;
temp_storeid number (38,0);
temp_sales number ; 
store_count number;
/*  sales_store number; */
BEGIN   
create table store_table as 
select distinct id_dmstore 
from input_table_1
order by store_id;   

select count(distinct attribute) into column_count from look_up_table;
for ind in 1..column_count loop

    /* putting current value of attribute from look_up_table in temp variable*/
    select attribute into temp_atr_val from (
        select attribute, rownum rwn
        from 
        (
           select distinct attribute
           from look_up_table
           order by attribute
        )
    ) where rwn = ind;

    select count( value ) into val_count from look_up_table
   where ATTRIBUTE = temp_atr_val;

    for ind in 1..val_count loop

   /* putting current value_for_atr for corresponding attribute from look_up_table in temp variable*/
        select value_for_atr into temp_val from 
         (
          select value_for_atr, rownum rwn
          from look_up_table
        where ATTRIBUTE = temp_atr_val
         ) where rwn = ind;


      select name_of_col into temp_name from 
      (
      select name_of_col, rownum rwn
      from look_up_table
       where ATTRIBUTE = temp_atr_val
      /* and VALUE_FOR_ATR = temp_val*/
       ) where rwn = ind;

 select count (STORE_id )into store_count from store_table;

 for ind in 1..column_count loop

  select store_id into temp_storeid from (
        select id_dmstore, rownum rwn
        from store_table
        order by store_id
        )
     where rwn = ind;

 select sum(net_sales_home) into temp_sales
 from input_table_1
 where temp_atr_val = temp_val
 and store_id = temp_storeid;


dbms_output.put_line (temp_sales);
 end loop; 
       /* SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN temp_atr_val = temp_val THEN net_sales_home ELSE 0 END) into temp_variable
       FROM schemafinal_1;

 dbms_output.put_line (temp_val);
*/
/*temp_variable := temp_variable/sales_store; */

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE SAR ADD ('||temp_name||' number)'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' UPDATE SAR b 
SET b.'||temp_name||' = :temp_variable' using temp_variable;

END LOOP;
END LOOP;   
END;
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you *have* a question?

Comment: hey sorry seems earlier my question didn't explain what i want. have edited it. actually i want to select sum of sales from input_table_1 where column name is as stored in temp_atr_val and value in that column is as stored in temp_val

Comment: I have altered your tags to Oracle and PL/SQL as this is what it appears you are using. Your code _will not work_ as you are creating a table in procedural code without using execute immediate, which you're not able to do; even if you put the creation into an execute immediate your code will still not compile as the _table does not exist_ at compile time and you are selecting from it. You are selecting from this table **without having put any data into it**. Are you sure that this is the way you want to go? I would go away and have a rethink about what you are doing.

Comment: From the look of what I think you're doing, it seems you're trying to build a dynamic pivot query - try searching for those terms

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a new column to store your data, and seeing as every time a new value appears in your temp variable a new column would be created, why don't you try this:
Create two new columns and call them column_name and column value. This way you can store the name of the column and the value that would be stored in it.
Later, to select from that column, instead of doing:

```
select column_name from table;
```

you would do:

```
select column_value from table where column_name = temp_variable;
```

If I understand what you were trying to do, of course...

Comment: I am facing problem in selecting the sum of sales and putting it in temp_sales as in the where clause i am not using the column name but a temporary variable which has the name of column stored in it.This part of code is not working for me:
select sum(net_sales_home) into temp_sales
 from input_table_1
 where temp_atr_val = temp_val
 and store_id = temp_storeid;

Comment: I know what you were trying to do. I was suggesting a different, simpler approach. If you really want to do that, remember the table must already have the column declared before you do the select. Also, for the select you can use execute immediate.

Comment: i tried it with execute immediate but doesn't work for me.
i am creating an automation code. so the column name or value in it may change.